# Javascript onkeydown a function

Tags: javascript

```js
function Test(event) {
  console.log(event.key + ' ' + event.which + ' ' + event.code);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="Test(this)">
```

**Result:**

```
undefined undefined undefined
```

**Reason:** I use this method because I need to generate multiple input text (dynamic) on run time.

**Please anyone help me, Thank in advance.**

Comment: Because you're passing `this`, not the event...

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `event` and not `this`

```js
function Test(event) {
  console.log(event.key + ' ' + event.which + ' ' + event.code);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="Test(event)">
```